# PHP page reloading without reason and $_SESSION value change

Tags: php, session, authentication

I am developing a simple login page in PHP/MySQL/Jquery but I have a strange behavioral: seems the page was reloaded without reason.
The code of index.php file is:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['key'] = hash('sha256',mt_rand());
error_log($_SESSION['key']);
// Print login page
include('views/login.phtml');
```

In the log message I found this rows:

```
[Wed Aug 29 23:21:05.323260 2018] [:error] [pid 99929] [client 127.0.0.1:57520] cb2d68d0a6307371311323894ad074a848a3f2a79d4778d571c38c2f42182f58
[Wed Aug 29 23:21:06.274971 2018] [:error] [pid 99929] [client 127.0.0.1:57520] 877786f919927f0c6be61afbb893a774f94f54c862eacf834be9f9968993a09a, referer: http://site.local:8080/index.php
```

Like the page was reloaded twice! If I open Chrome tool for page inspection a new row was added. I ask the source code with right click on the page, a new row was added. I don't understand why! Can you help me?

Comment: if you exclude your include does it still happen?

Comment: Yes! is the same.

Comment: is there more code in index.php?

Comment: Write `$_SESSION['key'] = 'abcdef';` instead. Any change then?

Comment: @dakis: I delete all other code but the result is the same. I put your text into the session, but into the log, I found two or three rows every time I reload the page.

Comment: How do you call index.php? Are you including it in some other page? And clear the cache and sessions before any new test.

Comment: I call index.php directly from the address bar. I have the following .htaccess file: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,NC,L]`. I deleted sessions and cache data and now I obtain only one key but two line of error_log: `Thu Aug 30 06:52:26.619267 2018] 25c73520e69f4bf229811e8e46ffe7d80471544b9bee15ed25044b86be4115ad
[Thu Aug 30 06:52:27.402704 2018] 25c73520e69f4bf229811e8e46ffe7d80471544b9bee15ed25044b86be4115ad, referer: http://site.local:8080/`

Comment: I have do another test: delete the .htaccess configuration. In this case the session id doesn't change, but the rest of website doesn't work! any idea? Thanks